# Setup MEAN app on digital ocean using nginx

Tags: nginx, node.js, digital-ocean

I am trying to setup a Nodejs + Angularjs application on digitalocean. I separated the frontend(angularjs) and backend(nodejs) into two nodejs servers each running on ports 3000 and 4000 respectively. I want the angularjs app to be served on mydomain.com and the backend server to be served via the subdomain api.mydomain.com. My nginx configuration is:

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com;
    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;  
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}    

server {
    server_name api.mydomain.com;
    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;  
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }
}
```

The following is the DNS configuration for the droplet:

```
Type     Host                  Value                   TTL
A   api.mydomain.com  directs to IP_ADD_OF_DROPLET    3600
A   mydomain.com      directs to IP_ADD_OF_DROPLET    1800
NS  mydomain.com      directs to ns1.digitalocean.com 1800
NS  mydomain.com      directs to ns2.digitalocean.com 1800
NS  mydomain.com      directs to ns3.digitalocean.com 1800
```

mydomain.com is configured to used the 3 digitalocean nameservers (ns_.digitalocean.com)

I need help regarding this, so that the api server is accessible (api.mydomain.com).

Comment: Your problem is with your DNS setup so you need to provide more information about your DNS configuration.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Please provide full output of `dig @8.8.8.8 api.mydomain.com` and `dig @ns_.digitalocean.com api.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NS records for `mydomain.com` are pointing to the `ns37.domaincontrol.com` and `ns38.domaincontrol.com` which belong to GoDaddy so no one knows about your settings on `ns_.digitalocean.com`. You need to set `NS` records in your domain control panel on your domain registrar (I assume GoDaddy) to point to the Digital Ocean name servers or alternatively create necessary `A` records for @ and api on your domain control panel.